# Thrown exception stopping application despite being in a try block

Tags: vb.net

I have an async function that makes a call to an API, but sometimes there is bad data and I want an exception to be thrown to stop other subsequent procedures from having to run. The Async procedure looks like this:

```
             public async Function getInfo(url as string) as task(of string)
                Dim htpRes As HttpResponseMessage = Await url.GetAsync().ConfigureAwait(False)
                Dim result = htpRes.Content.ReadAsStringAsync.Result
                If result = "" Then
                   Throw New Exception("API Failed")
                Else
                   Return result
                End If
             End Function
```

That function is called by a procedure that looks like this:

```
    sub hitAllAPIs(apiList As List(Of String))
        For each i In apiList
            Try
                Dim info As String = getInfo(i)
                doOtherStuffWithInfo(info)
            Catch ex As Exception
                logError
            End Try
        Next
    End sub
```

The desired behavior is for the forloop in 'hitAllAPIs' to keep running even if an exception is thrown within 'getInfo'. Instead, what happens is that the exception gets hit and stops the code from running, whether I'm in Debug mode or Release mode. If I'm not there to babysit it and hit 'continue' then the forloop will just stop and the program won't run anymore. Once I hit 'continue', btw, the 'Catch' will work and the error will be logged.

The issue is that I need this to all happen automatically and that's not happening. I can't just eliminate the exception and check the function for a null value, since this is a very simplified version of my code and the function is actually called all over the place. I know that I can change my exception settings to simply skip over all exceptions like this, but this is happening even in Release mode to code that has been deployed. I can't imagine that my debugging exceptions should have an effect on code deployed in Release mode. In any case, I'm hoping someone can help me understand why this exception isn't being automatically handled by the try block.

Thanks!

Comment: Because the IDE is setup to Break when an exception (of the actual Type) is thrown. You have the option to set it otherwise, when the exception message pops up. BTW, why do you have something like: `Await url.GetAsync().ConfigureAwait(False)` and then `htpRes.Content.ReadAsStringAsync.Result`? What's that about? You *may* have a reason for `ConfigureAwait(False)`, but why not `Await htpRes.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`? You should concentrate on that. What kind of application is this? Desktop, Web...

Comment: Thank you for the response. I understand that I can change my exceptions to avoid this in debug mode, but the bigger issue is that this is happening in Release mode and breaking the deployed code. As far as why I am awaiting the HTTP Response, it's probably just because I'm doing something dumb. I don't think that affects the underlying problem however.

Comment: If you deselect the exception (the *real* Exception) from the `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` in the `Exception Settings` pane, the exception won't cause a message box to pop up. The *real* exception, not `System.Exception`.

Comment: I would rather not change my exception settings, but in any case, the real problem is that this exception is breaking the code in release mode as well.

Comment: Those exception settings are used exactly for this reason: you want or you don't want your code, in the IDE, to break when an exception Type is thrown. That's a tool you use when is needed. If you don't want your code to break - using the Debug of Release Profile doesn't matter - deselect one or more exceptions, so Visual Studio won't break the execution. You can turn break mode on and off for one or more exceptions whenever you want. That's normal procedure. It has nothing to do with the behavior of your executable, it will treat exceptions as usual.

Answer (score 0):

It seems result = "" is an expected result not an exception. Using Try/Catch is rather heavy handed. Exception handling is for unexpected results. Get rid of the `Throw` in the `Function` and add and `If`  in the `For Each`.

```
Public Async Function getInfo(url As String) As Task(Of String)
    Dim htpRes As HttpResponseMessage = Await url.GetAsync().ConfigureAwait(False)
    Dim result = htpRes.Content.ReadAsStringAsync.Result
    Return result
End Function

Sub hitAllAPIs(apiList As List(Of String))
    For Each i In apiList
        Dim info As String = getInfo(i)
        If info = "" Then
            'Add an overload of logError that accepts a string
            logError("API failed")
        Else
            doOtherStuffWithInfo(info)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I agree in this particular code example it would be easy to handle the null result without an exception, but this is a simplified version of the code and I have to leave the exception there. I'm just trying to figure out why it is not being handled as it is encapsulated in a try block.